# Configure spring boot embedded tomcat - update setenv file

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

I want to configure spring boot's embedded tomcat server to use following configurations.

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk

JAVA_OPTS="-d64 -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -jcifs.http.domainController=dc.nc.example.com"

CATALINA_OPTS="-Dspring.profiles.active=hcServiceDev,authDev -Dsun.security.jgss.native=true - Dsun.security.jgss.lib=/usr/local/libexec/libjgssfix.so -Duser.timezone=GMT"

export JAVA_OPTS CATALINA_OPTS JPDA_OPTS JAVA_HOME
```

How can I do that?

I am running my application by executing file with the content below from eclipse.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class StructuredInterviewingApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(StructuredInterviewingApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to pass those arguments at the execution of the spring boot jar ?

Comment: What do you mean by that, I am running the application by executing this file from eclipse.

@SpringBootApplication
public class StructuredInterviewingApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(StructuredInterviewingApplication.class, args);
    }
}

Comment: Modify your "run configuration" to pass your above VM arguments.

Comment: VM Arguments don't have these variables. I am not sure how can I do that? Is there a way to update "setenv" file of embedded tomcat?

Comment: Just paste your whole list of JAVA_OPTS and CATALINA_OPTS inside the "VM arguments" textarea, they will work the same as if you had entered them in the command line .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can pass in jvmArguments to "spring-boot-maven-plugin". Example:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <jvmArguments>
            -Dsun.security.jgss.native=true -Dsun.security.jgss.lib=/usr/local/libexec/libjgssfix.so
        </jvmArguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```